# SHA-1 Hash a byte array vs a file stream

Tags: c#, sha1

I am writing an API that allows users to upload files (image, video, etc). I use a SHA-1 hash to make sure the same file isn't uploaded multiple times. Previously we only allowed smaller files so I was reading them into a byte array and hashing that but now we allow larger files so I am using a file stream. The problem is the SHA-1 algorithm returns a different hash. I need to figure out how to get the same hash regardless of the method, even if I have to turn the byte array into a file stream or something. However, I've tried writing the byte array to a temp file and reading it in and it returns the same hash as the byte array. Here is an example console app that shows what I am doing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = "C:\\CUWCDFileStorage\\temp\\test.png";
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile(bytes));   // Returns B7F6D90C30233F91FCEFE05FB49679F8B26C9D80
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile(stream));  // Returns DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile2(bytes));  // Returns B7F6D90C30233F91FCEFE05FB49679F8B26C9D80
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public static string Sha1HashFile(byte[] file)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(file)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile(Stream stream)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile2(byte[] bytes)
{
    string file = "C:\\CUWCDFileStorage\\temp\\test2.png";
    File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytes);
    return Sha1HashFile(File.OpenRead(file));
}
```

I've even tried to just put the byte array into a `MemoryStream` with `new MemoryStream(bytes)` but that didn't work either. It seems like once I have the file in a byte array it can't be put back.

EDIT:

I removed some code from my example because I thought MD5 was working. Here is the original code I was using to test:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = "C:\\CUWCDFileStorage\\temp\\test.png";
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Md5HashFile(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine(Md5HashFile(stream));
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile(stream));
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile2(bytes));
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public static string Md5HashFile(byte[] file)
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(file)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile(byte[] file)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(file)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Md5HashFile(Stream stream)
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile(Stream stream)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile2(byte[] bytes)
{
    string file = "C:\\CUWCDFileStorage\\temp\\test2.png";
    File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytes);
    return Sha1HashFile(File.OpenRead(file));
}
```

See answer below for explanation of the problem.

Comment: Is the code as presented in your question the actual real code? Have you tried running the code exactly as written here? Because, the code example in your question is just fine and will not produce different hashes...

Comment: Also of note is that the second hash you list is that of an empty stream.

Comment: It's possible the stream is skipping some preamble bytes, I suppose.  It's unlikely, but this is the best I can come up with.  Can you check the first 3-4 bytes of the stream compared to the first 3-4 bytes of your array?  Are they identical?

Comment: @elgonzo you're right. The bottom example is what I am actually testing and now I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the stream is being read to the end when hashing the first way. That is causing the second hash to be wrong. Because of that, I need to either reopen a stream for the second hash or rewind the stream to the beginning before hashing the second way. Here is the solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = "C:\\CUWCDFileStorage\\temp\\test.png";
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Md5HashFile(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine(Md5HashFile(stream));
    }

    using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile(stream));
        Console.WriteLine(Sha1HashFile2(bytes));
    }

    Console.Read();
}

public static string Md5HashFile(byte[] file)
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(file)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile(byte[] file)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(file)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Md5HashFile(Stream stream)
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile(Stream stream)
{
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(sha1.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "");
    }
}

public static string Sha1HashFile2(byte[] bytes)
{
    string file = "C:\\CUWCDFileStorage\\temp\\test2.png";
    File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytes);
    return Sha1HashFile(File.OpenRead(file));
}
```